# Mouse not responding suddenly - how to solve it?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

On my laptop, sometimes the mouse does not respond at all. For example, when I open Outlook I am not able to select anything. When I click on mail nothing happens. I cannot even click and check the time/month or anything.

When I open the Chrome browser, if I experience the  same issue, then I used to click on the tab and select `reopen closed tab`, and then my mouse starts to work.

What is this issue, and how can I fix it?

I am using Windows 7 on a Lenovo W520 laptop.

Comment: Restart. Does it still happen. Use an external mouse, does it still happen?

Comment: Yes, already I use the external mouse only. still getting issues. in case if I am not use the external mouse the internal mouse behaves very bad